# How to listen for USB tethering activation by user?

Tags: android

Does Android do any broadcast when USB tethering is checked by the user?

Or perhaps, how can I access this status?

I would like to detect this change in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. 
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.TETHER_STATE_CHANGED");
yourApplicationContext.registerReceiver(this, ifilter);

Refer this code (ConnectivityManager.java)
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java#L282